# small dots appears in mozilla firefox but not in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, compatibility

I have mad a simple static web page. All works fine in Chrome but when i open the same page in firefox, small dots begin to appear with hyperlinks. I tried to find out but failed. If any one has an idea, please do share. It will be very of you people.

Images are attached for both Chrome and Firefox respectively.[image: Chrome Result]

[image: FireFoxResult]

Answer (score 0):

I was using 'ul' and 'li' tags. So, I added the following CSS and it was fixed.

> .menuItem ul li{ 
>       list-style-type: none; 
>   }